# JavaScript button click should append a input field to it's own div

Tags: javascript, html

I get troubles with the`EventListeners` if I use `innerHTML+=` to append a new input field, since there is a caching problem I guess.

```
<div id="frame">

  <input type="button"  id="btn"/>

</div>
```

JS

```
   document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
       divframe.innerHTML+="  <input ... />..."
   });
```

I simply want if the user presses the button over and over again, there will be a new input and buttons.( with their own EventListeners <- unnecessary right now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ussing innerHTML use appendChild, so the first and the following buttons wont lose his event, and for the new elements you could add onclick event:

```
<div id="frame">
  <input type="button" value="Add" class="addBtn">
</div>
<script>function appendBtn(){
    var newBtn = document.createElement("input");
  newBtn.onclick = appendBtn;
  newBtn.value = "Add";
  newBtn.classname = "addBtn";
  newBtn.type = "button"
    document.getElementById("frame").appendChild(newBtn);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("addBtn")[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    appendBtn()
})</script>
```

Comment: You just taught me multiple things at once, please  spend 20 seconds for structuring :))

Answer (score 1):

You have to create element then append element into div. You can try this:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {  
  var div = document.getElementById("frame");   
  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");   
  div.appendChild(input); 
});
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

`divframe.innerHTML+=...` rewrites inner HTML and removes event listeners (if any) from child elements. You need to `addEventListener` again. Below is (useless but working) code. Note that only the first button remains clickable because `getElementById` returns only one (first) element with the same id. As it is said in other answers better use `appendChild`.

```js
var divFrame=document.getElementById('frame');
function setListener(){
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',
function(){
divFrame.innerHTML+=divFrame.innerHTML;
setListener();
});
}
setListener();
```

```html
<div id="frame">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click" />
</div>
```